# Conditional constraint based on value in another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

With Postgres, I'm not sure how to set this up. I have two tables (pseudocode):

```
Table A
ID int
Unique bool

Table B
TableA_ID int
UserID int
```

What I want is if Unique in a row in Table A is true, to set a constraint on all rows in Table B that reference that TableA_ID row, the constraint being that (TableA_ID, UserID) are unique. But only for those rows that reference that particular Table A row.

**Edit**: This is for a database system. That is, each row in Table A describes a table of data (name, description, what the columns are, etc), and each row in Table B contains the values for a row in a table from Table A, along with some meta data like who created the row. We want to have the ability to designate some tables such that each user can only add one row to them, while other tables we don't care.

Comment: This idea seems to have problems.  Let's suppose that there are several (TableA_ID, UserID) records at first, and `Unique` is set to false.  What happens when unique gets updated to true for that A value?  Do you go in a delete a bunch of records in B?

Comment: The update to the Table A row would fail, I would expect.

Comment: It isn't possible to have a unique constraint on a portion of the table AFAIK.  Maybe if you describe the business problem an alternative can be given.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There are partial unique indexes. But I don't think that will help here.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Then post an answer if you have one :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't see the light any more than you do, just wanted to point it out. I agree that the OP should describe the business problem.

Comment: You always post wicked Postgres answers, this is why I asked :-)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I should think you could use a partial unique index if you copied the `unique` column into `Table B`, and used a foreign key with cascading updates to ensure it matches and is maintained. Only remaining obstacle seems to be the initial population of that column during `insert`. In [tag:sql-server] I'd be using a view to mimic the existing table B definition and use a separate backing table that includes the column as the basis of the view, and a trigger on the view would care for population. Any similar tricks in Postgres?